Need to extend the certificate profile validity on Azure trusted signing accounts
I have created a Private certificate profile in azure trusted signing account method. But it was valid for 3 days only, after 3 days, the certificate profile will get auto-renewal for next 3 days. How could I extend the validity for more than 1 year?
Have tried with deleting the certificate profile & trying to add again, But there was no option to extend the validity.

You can't extend the validity of the certificate delivered by Azure Trusted Signing, it's limited to 3 days by design. You have to timestamp the signatures to ensure they remain valid after the certificate expires.
